# HTTP session security and Session ID

Tags: web-services, http, security, https, webserver

If typical web-server determines user by Session-ID (that stored in cookies) - what prevents me from Session-ID substitution from another confidant User, such that i can do things like an Authenticated / Authorized user ? Are there any other mechanism to determine truly session ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Session ID is usually a secure generated token, that expires after some time.
So yes, if you get a token from a different user, you could impersonate him.

In reality, guessing this token is way harder than even guessing the users password. And you only have a very short time-frame to do so, after which the token expires.

Comment: Wow, thanks! `The Session ID is usually a secure generated token` - can you please provide more info (what is a token, how does it transmitted, if it `generated`, how does webserver know about algorithm to decrypt it) ? Or where i can gather it myself ? I'm dummy in this issue.

Comment: Of course there are different ways to do this, but the most common one is probably JWT. You can read about it on their page here https://jwt.io/